# Implementation of specfical region refresh with Java Swing

Tags: java, optimization

The number of models that my swing application needs to display is currently 2000 to 10000 images. After multiple zooming or using for a period of time, the memory continues to increase and will not decrease,How can I optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to recommend anything without knowing more about the environment, but I'll list some general tips:

- You resize images every time you zoom in/out. This creates new images rapidly, especially if you zoom in using the mouse wheel or some other tool that fires events rapidly. Consider creating the image after the resizing has finished.
- Don't hold references to unused images. This means you shouldn't store all the resized images, only the used ones.
- Probably you don't need every image in every state of the
  application - consider creating a loading screen which is shown while your application loads and resizes the used images, and discards the previous ones. (It does not have to be an actual loading screen or animation)
- I've never seen a small or medium-scale project which needed 10k unrelated images. You might be storing animations per-frame, which is way less efficient than using video formats.
- If you have many similar images, consider not loading them from file but instead paint them dynamically (you have a base image and paint over it using the component's Graphics).
- Call the garbage collector. This should free up any unused space in the memory.

Comment: In my limited experience with, I always need to redraw the top container and its sub-containers, think the main problem is here,  after all, Swing application can not do local refresh.

Comment: Final, I used clip to implement the region refresh